# Duplicate a div after changing value of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to to duplicate a div after changing a select like in this link :
http://jsfiddle.net/ranell/mN6nm/5/
I have [object] instead of my lists :(
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you are appending a string to an object? `var append_str = $('#dvCatGr').clone().appendTo('.dvCat');` and `temp_str = temp_str + append_str;`

Comment: Yes this is the problem , but if write  append_str="<div id='dvCatGr'>" it works (i've many div duplicated).
I don't know how making the same thing by cloning a div N times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mN6nm/20/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var original = $("#dvCatGr");

    $('#sctChambre').change(function() {
        var total = parseInt($(this).val());

        $('#dvCat').empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            $("#dvCat").append($(original).clone().attr("id", "dvCatGr"+ i));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've a question about the name of my select , for exemple, i've many select with the same name=sctAdulte , how it is possible to assign a unique name for each select?
sctAdulte1
sctAdulte2
sctAdulte3..
it's about submitting form, with the same name, i could'nt catch all POST informations :(

Comment: Take a look at the answer where it says `.attr("id", "dvCatGr"+ i));`. That's effectively doing exactly that, except with the "id" attribute instead of "name." If you want to do the same thing with name, then just change it to `.attr({ id:"dvCatGr"+ i, name:"sctAdulte"+ i }));`. Or better yet, just give them all a name of `sceAdulte[]` (note the open-close square brackets). Then they will be passed as an array. This works with PHP, at least. I assume it works with others as well.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is the name sctAdulte is the name of the select that is the child of the div.
with this code it attribute a name for the div, and do not modify the name of the select

Comment: My mistake. `.attr("id", "dvCatGr"+ i).children("select").attr("name", "sctAdulte"+ i));`. But again, It would probably be better to just give all of the <select> elements a name of `sctAdulte[]` and then your server will likely receive it as an array.

Comment: Thank you,it's more complicated than i think :/ 
div 
    span 
        select name="sctAdulte" 
        select name="sctEnfant" 
        select name="sctBebe"
Even the select is not the direct child of the div, i've tried children("span").children("select") but it didn't work for me.
and after that, i've failed to clone the three select into each span with three name different and libelled from 1 to 5 sctAdulte0,sctEnfant0,sctBebe0,sctAdult1,sctEnfant1...

Comment: i've tried this : unsuccessful..
$("#dvCat").append($(original).clone().attr("id", "dvCatGr"+ i).children("select").attr({ name:"sctBebe"+ i, name:"sctEnfant"+ i,name:"sctAdulte"+ i }));

Comment: You have two options. Option 1 is to change the names of all three <select> elements. The names should be `sctAdulte[]`, `sctEnfant[]`, and `sctBebe[]`. Each one will be received by the server as an array. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mN6nm/21/) for an example.

Comment: If you don't want to use that option, and you ***really*** insist on each one having its own unique name, then you can do this: `$("#dvCat").append($(original).clone().attr("id", "dvCatGr"+ i)); $("#dvCatGr"+ i).find("select").each(function() { $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + i); });`. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mN6nm/24/) for an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mN6nm/16/)**?

```
$('#sctChambre').change(function() {
    var total = parseInt($(this).val());
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        $('#dvCat').after($('#dvCatGr').clone().attr('id', 'c' + i));
    }
});​
```

Comment: oh nice, thank you, it's almost what i'm looking for, but it's just cumulative.
Maybe should I delete all the div at the begginning of the for?

Comment: You could use jQuery's .empty() function to do that if you like.

Comment: Keep in mind that emptying the `#dvCat` element will also delete the object you're trying to clone, so you need to keep a copy of it somewhere before you delete it. But actually, you're not putting the new copies into the `#dvCat` element. You're appending them *after* that element. So `empty()` wouldn't really work too well with this example.